# How to dynamically change URL of liferay iframe portlet?

Tags: url, iframe, liferay

I need to create a page with two portlets. The first one will need to change the url source of the second iframe portlet on click. However, the requirement is that the page should not be reloaded.

Is it possible to implement? If yes, then how?

I read from [iframe documentation](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Iframe+Portlet#section-Iframe+Portlet-Change+the+URL+dynamically) that the page can be changed, but it requires the page to be reloaded.

Comment: both the portlets are iframe?

Comment: the second one is an iframe. The first one does not have to be an iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I prefer doing it Ajax way rather than iframe, in JSR 268 Inter portlet communication can be achieved. for more details, you can visit this link.

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Inter-portlet+communication

Comment: thanks for reply. However, i have a separate web server running on IIS, and need to access a web-page on it, so that's why i decided to use an iframe. The requirement is that the user will choose some attributes from the first portlet, and then clicks on a BUTTON, and depending on which attributes he selected, the second iframe portlet's URL source should be like 'http://localhost:2323/webapp.aspx?attrib1=XXXX&attrib2=XXXX'